# private_pub with Puma on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I'm trying to deploy my production app on Heroku. I'm using both private_pub and Puma in my app.

I wanted to start both using this procfile :

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
web: bundle exec rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -p $PORT -E production
```

But it fails, it seems like you can have only one web process running at a time on Heroku apps. Is there a way to initialize both ?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a working solution? What kind of app, rails? What version?

Comment: Yep, I did ! Actually, the private-pub gem does not need to run on the same app as your puma. Follow this tutorial : http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/deploying-private-pub-on-heroku/

Comment: @fro_oo basically, all you have to do is to create an heroku app which only job will be to keep the private_pub running. This way, everytime a hook is triggered on your main app, it goes through this new app and triggers the event.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer. Maybe you should add the answer to your own question. ;-) Cheers

Comment: @fro_oo yes, completely forgot about this question. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so basically you cannot run the 2 processes on heroku at the same time. An easy alternative is to create a dedicated heroku app which sole purpose will be to maintain the Pubsub server running. To do so, just follow  [this tutorial](http://thegreatcodeadventure.com/deploying-private-pub-on-heroku)